# Photoshop batch process pausing on every action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch

I recently upgraded to Photoshop CS6 and imported my actions from my previous version.

I am trying to run a batch script to automate an action.

Every step seems to require a input click. In other words, the batch is not automatically going through the list in the actions. For example, in Action 27 below, after `Image Size`, I have to click OK. Then, after `Canvas Size`, I have to click OK again, &c.

How can I fully automate this process?

[image: list of tasks in Action 27, starting with Image Size and Canvas Size]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, very simple! Look at your first screen shot and notice that little square light grey icon on the left side of every action step. Clicking this icon for every chosen step will disable the need for user input.

Comment: helped me in almost 2019