# import actions from older version in photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am having problems when i import actions from previous versions of Photoshop in CS6.
The `actions` pause and asks for user confirmation on each step.
It defeats the purpose of automating tasks.
Anyone know how to fix this so the steps operate smoothly without these breaks?

Comment: Publish it as an answer, then accept it after an appropriate interval.

Comment: looks like i answered my own question<br/>
http://superuser.com/questions/457340/photoshop-batch-process-pausing-on-every-action

Comment: @Xavierjazz i tried this and it left it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed a problem where actions stop at every step when imported into a newer Photoshop version, but here is an example of how it likely happened:

This action set will close all open documents without saving them.
[Original Action Set (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZCYm.png)

["Accidentally" Clicking on the empty box (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPXP9.png)

[Now ALL steps will stop (highlighting added)(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC8Un.png)

NOTE: The example shown above actually does NOT stop at each step because there is no user input. Notice how the "Close document without save" is "No".

Apologies... apparently I do not have enough reputation to embed images, so you'll have to click the links to see the files.

In  Summary: If you accidentally click the empty space to the left of the action set name, it turns "interaction ON" for every action step in every action of the set.

It does warn you because the operation is not un-doable ... but it's easy to miss.